# Do variable declaration with let and const in JavaScript work differently in block scope and global scope?

Tags: javascript, hoisting, executioncontext

Here are two examples:

```
console.log(x);
let x = 4;
```

throws Reference Error *x is not defined*;

```
{
console.log(y);
let y = 3;
}
```

throws Reference Error *Cannot access 'y' before initialization*;

So, my question is: why JS engine interprets these two cases differently?
At the creation phase *let* is uninitialized, and only at execution phase it has value *undefined* and then assigned to a value.

Comment: Not really, no. They just create different error messages. (IIRC the error message in block scopes was the same at some point, but got improved to be more specific about the TDZ)

Comment: No, they both are different cases.

Comment: Because the `let x` portion is hoisted to the top of the enclosing scope. So `x` is actually declared before the `console.log`, but because of the temporal dead zone, you get the error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i know why i have an error. I'm asking why errors are different